# Error because of using scientific notation

Tags: c++

I attempted a Hackerearth tutorial [question](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/introduction-to-dynamic-programming-1/tutorial/) and was able to solve it correctly using following code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
        const long int MOD = 1000000007;
        const long int SIZE = 100001;
        long int t, n;
        long int cache[SIZE];

        cache[0] = 1;

        for (long int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++) {
            cache[i] = ( i * cache[i-1] ) % MOD;
        }

        cin >> t;
        while (t--) {
            cin >> n;
            cout << cache[n] << endl;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

However when using scientific notation to write MOD or SIZE, online judge reports incorrect answers. What am I missing here?

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
        const long int MOD = 10e9+7;
        const long int SIZE = 100001;
        long int t, n;
        long int cache[SIZE];

        cache[0] = 1;

        for (long int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++) {
            cache[i] = ( i * cache[i-1] ) % MOD;
        }

        cin >> t;
        while (t--) {
            cin >> n;
            cout << cache[n] << endl;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `1E9` is a floating point literal.  While not technically incorrect, using a floating point literal to initialise a `long` is bad practice.   Quite a few compilers  [can be deliberately configured to] (a) issue a warning on such things and (b)  treat warnings like that as an error, and fail to compile.    I'd guess the "online judge" is doing exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scientific notation means “constant multiplied by ten to the power of x”. If you want `1000000007` you need `1e9`, meaning “one followed by nine zeroes.” Now you use `10e9` which is “ten followed by nine zeroes” or “one followed by ten zeroes” so you’re off by a factor of ten.

Comment: Well that was an embarrassing mistake